# Plot learning curve for multiclass classification with cross validation using caret package in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, plot, neural-network, r-caret

I have a multiclass classification problem (with 10 classes)that I am trying to solve using the neural network option 'mxnet' in the caret package in R. I'm using a 10-fold cross validation during training and would like to plot a learning curve for this to figure out whether/how the model is overfitting. I have modified the solution given in this post ([Plot learning curves with caret package and R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370827/plot-learning-curves-with-caret-package-and-r#)) to fit my data. However, since the learning curve is being recorded over each one of the resamples, not all factors/classes (1-10) are present in each fold, which leads to the following error:

> Error: One or more factor levels in the outcome has no data

I have also tried to use the builtin function of caret with learning_curve_dat, but I encounter the same error message.

Is there a way to bypass this problem of not all factors being present in each one of the folds?

Comment: I found this question with similar topic regarding factors in CV: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946930/r-cross-validation-on-a-dataset-with-factors. Would stratified sampling be useful for you? https://gist.github.com/Bergvca/c1df8e579005e3cd82e8d3c8b009403a

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @JonnyPhelps! I was already using a stratified random split with createDataPartition to create a training and test set, but the problem seems to occur during the 10-fold cross-validation. I have also implemented a stratified cross-validation with createFolds( ) to assure that all classes are represented in each fold, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: @EkabaBisong I'm using your solution from the post linked above, but I can't seem to get it to work for a multiclass problem. Do you have a suggestion on how to get it to work?

Comment: If there are some tiny classes, could look at upSampling your data. https://rdrr.io/cran/caret/man/downSample.html. Here is a good tutorial I read about unbalanced data: https://shiring.github.io/machine_learning/2017/04/02/unbalanced